# How can I keep screws secure over time in a loft bed kit?

Tags: furniture, bedroom

I just ordered [this bed](https://www.wayfair.com/baby-kids/pdp/mack-milo-edinburgh-full-loft-bed-w000012057.html) and a lot of the reviews say that the screws loosen and have to be retightened often.

I'm wondering what the impact to the wood itself, over time, if I used wood glue in the holes during assembly. Would this cause the wood to split or anything from whatever pressure changes that (normally) cause the screws to loosen up?

This may be a completely dumb question, I don't know why I'm second guessing myself; I think it would be fine but I don't want to learn by trial and error with this one.

Thanks!

Comment: These type of beds usually have some wobble (technical term) in them due to the design and size of the structural supports. This results in bolts and screws loosening.I couldn't tell from the website if it has wood screws or bolt mechanisms. With wood screws I doubt that gluing them in will help very much. Lateral forces will probably still loosen them but you can try it. With bolts you might try Loctite on them.

Comment: putting diagonal braces on the three sides may go a long way toward reducing wobble .... making the bottom horizontal panels wider would also reduce wobble

Comment: ( https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/189199/changing-loft-beds-beam-to-diagonal-braces/189204#189204) may help.

Comment: If it uses wood screws, drill the holes out and use bolts, flat washers, lock washers, nuts ( and loc-tite-- if you don't anticipate moving or disassembly in the future )

Comment: Thank you everyone so much! I am unboxing the bed today so I will see if it's bolts are wood screws. I was also thinking some type of flexible (not fixed) glue. I was also thinking of adding wainscoting panels around the sides to help with stability  shipped from southern California to Arizona so the weather isn't too different so I'm hoping there won't be excessive expansion/contraction issues. This was my first post on this site and I really appreciate all the insight and help! As a single mom that tries to do everything herself I have a feeling I'll be on here frequently :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use something a little less rigid since you probably *want* to be able to snug the screws down the road. Wood tends to shrink and deform, and if you lock the screws you won't be able to do followup snugging.

I'd use a low-strength threadlocker compound. This should allow snugging without needing to remove screws and reapply.

Comment: Interesting answer! Are there any common guidelines ("rules of thumb") for the rate at which wood like this will shrink?  Obviously, different types of wood have different properties, but perhaps there are some general guidelines.  If you feel it is appropritate, I can write a separate question.

Comment: You're way overthinking this. What difference does such a number make? How will it change your strategy?

Comment: It depends on how long the furniture will remain assembled.

Comment: Frankly, @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket wood will contract _and expand_ seasonally. Yes, it _might_ get a little drier over time than it was when it was initially assembled (depends on humidity levels where it was manufactured vs where it's installed), but in general, after 6-12 months, it will have gotten to it's "steady state" in its current locale, and won't shrink any smaller (barring long-term changes in humidity levels).

Comment: Check out [Woodworking.se] for all _sorts_ of gory details about drying lumber. It applies as much after a product is made as it does the raw wood prior to manufacture.

Answer (score 0):

Wood glue is fine.  Often wooden chairs have the legs screwed and glued.  I've certainly done that to wooden chairs that have had wobble with great success.